# Getting a predictable Pandas DataFrame from (sparse) JSON

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I'm getting JSON from an API. This API omits `null` values (properties which are `null` are not sent over the wire), thus the data can be sparse. The properties contain a mix of, string, numeric, boolean, unix-timestamps, ISO8601-timestamps and ISO8601-durations.

Here's an example JSON (as a Python list/dict) with all data types

```
        data_full = [
            {'name': 'alice', 'lastname': 'foo', 'value': 1.11, 'unix_ts': 1591848156000, 'iso_ts': '2020-05-17T12:33:44Z',
             'iso_dur': 'PT1H11M', 'bool_val': True},
            {'name': 'clair', 'lastname': 'bar', 'value': 3.33, 'unix_ts': 1591648156000, 'iso_ts': '2020-03-17T12:33:44Z',
             'iso_dur': 'PT3H33M', 'bool_val': True},
        ]
```

Sparse data can be lacking fields on any row, or for all rows, or the API result can also be completely empty. Examples

```
        some_fields_missing_in_some_rows = [
            {'name': 'alice', 'lastname': 'foo', 'value': 1.23, 'unix_ts': 1591848156000,
             'iso_ts': '2020-05-17T12:33:44Z',
             'iso_dur': 'PT1H11M', 'bool_val': True},
            {'name': 'clair', }
        ]
        some_fields_missing_in_all_rows = [
            {'name': 'alice'},
            {'name': 'clair'}
        ]
        no_data = []
```

I convert this to a Pandas DataFrame using `json_normalize`. To allow for predictive further processing, I want that in all sparse cases the output dtype are the same as if the data was full, with the correct `NA` inserted in missing places. I struggle to get this missing values of the right type (np.nan or other).

The fully contained test-case below shows the problem (aka if you get the 4 tests to pass, I believe it's doing what I expect).

One explicit problems is how to create and populate with NaN an empty column of type `str`. 
Any feedback is appreciated.

```
import datetime
from typing import List, Tuple
from unittest import TestCase

import isodate
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


class TestDFNormalization(TestCase):
    def test_full_fields(self):
        jsList = [
            {'name': 'alice', 'lastname': 'foo', 'value': 1.11, 'unix_ts': 1591848156000,
             'iso_ts': '2020-05-17T12:33:44Z',
             'iso_dur': 'PT1H11M', 'bool_val': True},
            {'name': 'clair', 'lastname': 'bar', 'value': 3.33, 'unix_ts': 1591648156000,
             'iso_ts': '2020-03-17T12:33:44Z',
             'iso_dur': 'PT3H33M', 'bool_val': True},
        ]
        df = extract_df(js=jsList)
        print(df.dtypes)
        print(df)
        self.assert_dtypes_conform(df)
        self.assert_correct_NaNs(df, 2)  # no NaN, so all rows (=2) kept

    def test_sparse_fields(self):
        some_fields_missing_in_some_rows  = [
            {'name': 'alice', 'lastname': 'foo', 'value': 1.23, 'unix_ts': 1591848156000,
             'iso_ts': '2020-05-17T12:33:44Z',
             'iso_dur': 'PT1H11M', 'bool_val': True},
            {'name': 'clair', }
        ]
        df = extract_df(js=some_fields_missing_in_some_rows )
        print(df.dtypes)
        print(df)
        self.assert_dtypes_conform(df)
        self.assert_correct_NaNs(df, 1)  # some NaN, only 1 row kept

    def test_lacking_fields(self):
        some_fields_missing_in_all_rows  = [
            {'name': 'alice'},
            {'name': 'clair'}
        ]

        df = extract_df(js=some_fields_missing_in_all_rows )
        print(df.dtypes)
        print(df)
        self.assert_dtypes_conform(df)
        self.assert_correct_NaNs(df, 0)  # all NaN, no rows

    def test_no_data(self):
        no_data  = []

        df = extract_df(js=no_data )
        print(df.dtypes)
        print(df)
        self.assert_dtypes_conform(df)
        self.assert_correct_NaNs(df, 0)  # no rows

    def assert_dtypes_conform(self, df: pd.DataFrame) -> None:
        self.assertEqual("object", df['name'].dtype)
        self.assertEqual("object", df['lastname'].dtype)
        self.assertEqual("float", df['value'].dtype)
        self.assertEqual("datetime64[ns, UTC]", df['unix_ts'].dtype)
        self.assertEqual("datetime64[ns, UTC]", df['iso_ts'].dtype)
        self.assertEqual("timedelta64[ns]", df['iso_dur'].dtype)
        self.assertEqual("boolean", df['bool_val'].dtype)

    def assert_correct_NaNs(self, df: pd.DataFrame, expectedNumRowsAfterDropNA: int) -> None:
        self.assertEqual(expectedNumRowsAfterDropNA, len(df.dropna(subset=['lastname']).index))
        self.assertEqual(expectedNumRowsAfterDropNA, len(df.dropna(subset=['value']).index))
        self.assertEqual(expectedNumRowsAfterDropNA, len(df.dropna(subset=['unix_ts']).index))
        self.assertEqual(expectedNumRowsAfterDropNA, len(df.dropna(subset=['iso_ts']).index))
        self.assertEqual(expectedNumRowsAfterDropNA, len(df.dropna(subset=['iso_dur']).index))
        self.assertEqual(expectedNumRowsAfterDropNA, len(df.dropna(subset=['bool_val']).index))


def extract_df(js: List) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df = pd.json_normalize(js)
    create_cols_if_absent(df=df,
                          expected_cols=('name', 'lastname', 'value', 'unix_ts', 'iso_ts', 'iso_dur', 'bool_val'))
    # astype_per_column(df=df, column='name', dtype='str')
    # astype_per_column(df=df, column='lastname', dtype='str')
    # astype_per_column(df=df, column='value', dtype='float')
    parse_unix_ms(df=df, column='unix_ts')
    parse_iso(df=df, column='iso_ts')
    parse_dur(df=df, column='iso_dur')
    astype_per_column(df=df, column='bool_val', dtype='boolean')
    return df


def create_cols_if_absent(df: pd.DataFrame, expected_cols: Tuple) -> None:
    for col in expected_cols:
        if col not in df.columns:
            df[col] = np.nan  # or None or pd.NA or np.nan ?


def parse_unix_ms(df, column):
    df[column] = pd.to_datetime(df[column], unit='ms', origin='unix', utc=True)


def parse_iso(df, column):
    df[column] = pd.to_datetime(df[column], utc=True)


def parse_iso_duration(durationstring: str) -> datetime.timedelta:
    if not durationstring or pd.isna(durationstring):
        return None
    return isodate.parse_duration(durationstring)


def parse_dur(df, column) -> None:
    df[column] = pd.to_timedelta(
        df[column].apply(parse_iso_duration))  # why does to_timedelta() not support ISO8601 notation?


def astype_per_column(df: pd.DataFrame, column: str, dtype) -> None:
    df[column] = df[column].astype(dtype)
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, well it was very close. 
It should use the new (pandas >= 1.0) string type (`StringDtype`) in the `astype` call.

```
def extract_df(js: List) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df = pd.json_normalize(js)
    create_cols_if_absent(df=df,
                          expected_cols=('name', 'lastname', 'value', 'unix_ts', 'iso_ts', 'iso_dur', 'bool_val'))
    astype_per_column(df=df, column='name', dtype='string')
    astype_per_column(df=df, column='lastname', dtype='string')
    astype_per_column(df=df, column='value', dtype='float')
    parse_unix_ms(df=df, column='unix_ts')
    parse_iso(df=df, column='iso_ts')
    parse_dur(df=df, column='iso_dur')
    astype_per_column(df=df, column='bool_val', dtype='boolean')
    return df
```